# is there anyway to divide row in different col with only one ngfor iteration?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, col

I would like to put a text-box in col-6 and other types in other col-6 so they can be next to each other.

I have tried using 2 *ngFor iterations and it is displaying which I want but can we do with only one iteration?

[image]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hunqiq

Comment: One way to go about doing this is to, pre-process to group items that need to appear together in a row. Is there a specific criteria here that you want for pairing? E.g. If you want all textboxes to appear on left, in your component, separate out your form elements into text and non-text, iterate through them and combine them. Sepration by text based can be done using 'filter'.

Comment: Thanks zonaib for response... Yes I do have specific requirements to display all types separately... Can't we handle this directly on html instead of going in component?

Comment: It would be better to do this in component, reasons, the html can only display what you give it, right? e.g. if this was on the first text based element, asking it to look into all the next elements to find a matching one(non-text based) would be a performance hit, since it is being bound to a dynamic list of elements, which can change any time. This is just my opinion, and more better people will answer this, but i can help with separation of elements into row pairs.

Comment: Sure can you help me for this using component...  So I can handle each and every element order..

Answer (score 1):

Hi Bravo to achieve what you want you need to reorder you list in the component like this :

```
form_template = [
  {
    "type":"textBox",
    "label":"Name",
  },
  {
    "type":"number",
    "label":"Age"
  },
  {
    "type":"textBox",
    "label":"Name2",
  },
  {
    "type":"number",
    "label":"Age2"
  },
  {
    "type":"textBox",
    "label":"Name3",
  },
  {
    "type":"number",
    "label":"Age3"
  },
  {
    "type":"textBox",
    "label":"Name4",
  },
  {
    "type":"number",
    "label":"Age4"
  },
  {
    "type":"select",
    "label":"favorite book",
    "options":["Jane Eyre","Pride and Prejudice","Wuthering Heights"]
  }
]
```

Then you will be able to use one *ngFor like this :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="row">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let form_elem of form_template">
                  <div class="col-6">
                    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="form_elem.type">
                        <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 form-group">
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'textBox'" class="">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4"> {{form_elem.label}}</label>
                                    <input class="form-control col-sm-6" type="text" formControlName="{{form_elem.label}}" />
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'number'">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4"> {{form_elem.label}}</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="col-sm-6 form-control" formControlName="{{form_elem.label}}" />
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'select'" class="">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4"> {{form_elem.label}}</label>
                                    <select class="custom-select  col-sm-6" formControlName="{{form_elem.label}}">
                                        <option *ngFor="let opt of form_elem.options">
                                            {{opt}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'select'" class="">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                                                Example checkbox
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'select'" class="">
                                <div class="form-check-inline">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 1
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check-inline">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 2
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                  </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
        <input class="mt-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="save" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for the response.. Oussail..yes this can be good idea but what if the response comes from backend and if i want to skip any of the element and want to go next... line by showing black at that specific row... i cannot achieve with this method right?